# Drawing a lattice in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, overleaf, tikz-pic, lattice

Here is the figure I wanna draw:

> [image]

Could anyone show me how to draw this please?

Comment: Run `texdoc forest`

Comment: could you provide me with the details please ? I do not understand you.@Fran

Comment: You should have a program called `texdoc`. With some key word after it, you will obtain a manual or something else about this key word.  If you do not have a tex installation, there also a `texdoc` online, or simple search in google, or in CTAN, about the package `forest`.

Comment: He meant to run that on the command line, so if you're a Windows user open the start menu, enter `cmd` or `powershell` (doesn't matter much) and run it. In the newly opened window enter `texdoc forest` and hit enter. This should spawn your PDF viewer with the documentation of the `forest` package. If you're a Mac or Linux user just do the same in your terminal/shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a direct Ti*k*Z solution. Only placing the nodes and drawing the lines, but:

1. I made a macro `\nt` for the node texts. Call me lazy, but I didn't want to write `$\langle...\rangle$` each time.
2. The `tikzpicture` options `[x=1.4cm,y=1.8cm]` control the horizontal and vertical separations between nodes.
3. I used a `preaction` in the `style` `white border` to draw this white border needed in the line between `(A5)` and `(B1)`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{white border/.style={preaction={draw,white,line width=4pt}}}

\newcommand{\nt}[1]{$\langle#1\rangle$} % node text

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.4cm,y=1.8cm]% <-- change this numbers if you need (separations)
% nodes
\node at (0,0)    (I)  {$1$};
\node at (-4,1)   (A1) {\nt{\tau\sigma^2}};
\node at (-3,1)   (A2) {\nt{**}};
\node at (-2,1)   (A3) {\nt{**}};
\node at (-1,1)   (A4) {\nt{\tau}};
\node at (0,1)    (A5) {\nt{\sigma^4}};
\node at (-3,2)   (B1) {\nt{**}};
\node at (-1.5,2) (B2) {\nt{\sigma^4,\tau}};
\foreach\i in {3,4,5}
  \node at (1.5*\i-4.5,2) (B\i) {\nt{**}};
\node at (-1.5,3) (C1) {\nt{\sigma^2,\tau}};
\node at (0,3)    (C2) {\nt{\sigma}};
\node at (1.5,3)  (C3) {\nt{\sigma^2,\tau\sigma}};
\node at (0,4)    (G)  {$G$};
% lines
\foreach\i in {1,...,5}
  \draw (I)   -- (A\i);
\foreach\i in {1,2} \foreach\j[evaluate={\jj=int(2*\i+\j-2);}] in {1,2}
  \draw (B\i) -- (A\jj);
\foreach\i in {1,3} \foreach\j[evaluate={\jj=int(\i+\j-1);}] in {1,2,3}
  \draw (C\i) -- (B\jj);
\draw   (C2)  -- (B3);
\foreach\i in {1,2,3}
  \draw (G)   -- (C\i);
\foreach\i in {1,...,5}
  \draw[white border] (A5) -- (B\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the lattice:
[image]

Comment: I am using document class book, will any of the code parts change?

Comment: @Happy, no, it should work in any class as long as you include the Ti*k*Z package.